# How to calculate the time needed to calculate a SHA-256 hash?

Tags: security, hash, cryptography, sha

I need to find a SHA-256 hash function delay on a device which has 200 MHz CPU speed. How could I do that, is there anyone who has the answer for much faster or slower device?

Comment: It takes much more than knowing the MHz to know how fast a processor is. You really need to run the test yourself on the processor in question.

Comment: You may want to read around at http://s.tk/crypto

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The speed depends largely on the implementation and on the CPU specifics. A very rough estimate of the speed to be expected is to extrapolate [cycles per byte](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+4.+Symmetric+Cryptography+Fundamentals/4.14+Timing+Cryptographic+Primitives/) numbers to your particular device.

The [numbers](http://www.ouah.org/ogay/sha2/) do [vary](http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html), but let's be conservative and assume your SHA-256 implementation takes about 25 cycles/byte. Taking the reciprocal tells you that you get 1/25 of a byte per cyle. A 200 MHz processor has 200 mio cycles per second, so this gives you a theoretical throughput of 8 mio bytes/s, which is ~ 7,63 MB/s.

But this is just a very rough guess, if you want exact numbers, then the best thing you can do is to just benchmark the whole thing yourself.

Comment: Here is a useful link for time estimations for cryptographic functions. 

http://www.cryptopp.com/benchmarks.html

Comment: @Can that's actually the second link of "numbers vary", although it looks like one single link, I'll change that.

Comment: This is even further complicated with comparison of CPUs with and without Crypto based acceleration capabilities built in, and whether the library you build or are using, utilize that functionality!